# Gnome Shell opens as classic

Tags: 12.04, gnome, command-line

I'm running 12.04 on a Gateway LT4004u netbook. My graphics card is an integrated Intel GMA ​3600. I'm not sure whether or not it supports 3d, I have been unable to find any information via Google or Gateway's website.

I installed Gnome3 using the apt-get commands in the terminal. When I rebooted and ran "Gnome Shell" it opened up classic mode. I thought that my cursor might have slipped the first time, but on multiple retries logging in under gnome shell would open the gnome classic desktop. I even uninstalled Gnome Shell and reinstalled it with software center, but I still have the same problem.

I was wondering if this might be an issue with my graphics card? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

-Joe

Comment: Yeap, there is a major problem with GMA3600, and it is the recent reincarnation of Intel's infamous GMA500.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's due to your graphics card. GNOME Shell checks for certain features, and falls back to the classic mode, if they are not available.